# no LDAP in Libre Office 3.5 and 4.2

Tags: libreoffice, ldap

On a Kubuntu 12.04, I want to use an LDAP Server as Data-Source in LibreO, but i cannot find it in the list of possible connections. There is only: JDBC, OracleJDBC, Thunderbird/Icedove Address Book, tabledocument, dBASE, text, MySQL and ODBC.

I had installed Libre Office from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-2 .

now, i used  ppa-purge to remove the 4.2-version and reinstalled the libreoffice 3.5.7.2 Build-ID: 350m1(Build:2) from the ubuntu-repository.
And in this version, theres also no LDAP-Connection possible.

But in the libreoffice help-files, it is listed as an option.

Can somebody please help me by telling me which version i have to install or how i have to install it. Do i have to use the source-code, configure it with a specific parameter and compile it?

I would like to avoid compiling it. But I would compile it, if it's unavoidable. :-)

Thanks for any help. -messedupcoffeekid

P.S: @ tohuwawohu: thanks for answering. You are right. That was an understanding-mistake of mine. But still that function to connect to a LDAP-Server as Data-Source exists besides JDBC etc., it is listet in the libreOffice-Help-Files.

Edit.: I've found a tutorial (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xsoft/libreoffice.html) (for gentoo) for compiling libreoffice. Before compiling, you can use the autogen.sh to configure the program. And there is an option --with-system-openldap. As desciption i found: (If i understand correct) if that parameter is added to the autogen.sh, the libreoffice will be using a version of OpenLDAP, alreday installed on the system instead of downloading a new one.
Why is libreoffice using OpenLDAP anyways? Is it the same as with the libldap, or is it a hint, that it may work with a compiled version to use Adressbooks etc. from LDAP-Servers?

EDIT2:
Well, as I unterstand now, it would at least work, if I add the respective LDAP-Server within Evolution and use EvolutionLDAP within libreoffice as database-choice.

And i found out, that i had to install the .deb-package from the official libreoffice website instead of using the PPA for the availability of the evolution-LDAP-database-connection.

I will test an LDAP-Server this way soon and I will mark this thread as solved if it will work.

--messedupcoffeekid

Comment: i've edited my answer (but sadly still no solution...)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libldap` just allows to [access data from an ldap server related to the LibreOffice user](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/Administration_Guide/LDAP_Access). This isn't the same as an ldap server as data source. It may work using an LDAP JDBC driver, but i wasn't able to find a working example for this.

EDIT: built-in LDAP support is a os-dependent feature, at least since LO 4.0; see [LO bug 57417](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57417). It may be possible to access ldap data using a evolution / thunderbird address book as "proxy" (since Evolution / Thunderbird are able to access an ldap server as address source), but sadly i can't give further advice on this.

Comment: thank you tohuwawohu! a sad thing, with that bug. i added another question about this above.